# How to handle remote servers 500 error

Tags: c#, json, mailchimp, remote-server

I am sending data to MailChimp using a third party API and when I send the Json request the remote server returns a 500 error.

It is meant to return the error in Json, but I can't get what the error message is.

I have tried using a HttpWebRequest and then have it in a try catch with a WebException catch, but that still doesn't help.

Any Ideas of how I can catch what the error is?

**Error Message:**

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500)     Internal Server Error.

Source Error:


Line 1517:                    streamWriter.Close();
Line 1518:
Line 1519:                    var httpResponse =    (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Line 1520:                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
Line 1521:                    {


Source File: \App_Code\c#\MailChimpApi.cs    Line: 1519

Stack Trace:


[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.]
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +8527068
MailChimpManager.MakeAPICall(String apiAction, Object args) in \App_Code\c#\MailChimpApi.cs:1519

[MailChimpAPIException: You must specify a apikey value]
MailChimpManager.MakeAPICall(String apiAction, Object args) in \App_Code\c#\MailChimpApi.cs:1549
MailChimpManager.GetAllMembersForList(String API_KEY, String listId, String status, Int32 start, Int32 limit, String sort_field, String sort_dir) in \App_Code\c#\MailChimpApi.cs:784
__cms_form_send_newsletter.GetSyncMailChimps() in \__cms\form_send_newsletter.aspx.vb:73
__cms_form_send_newsletter.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in \__cms\form_send_newsletter.aspx.vb:14
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

**Request Code:**

```
try
        {
            ////  Call the API with the passed arguments:
            //var resultString = fullUrl.PostJsonToUrl(args);
            //results = resultString.Trim().FromJson<T>();

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullUrl);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = args.ToString();
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();

                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    results = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Trim().FromJson<T>();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            string errorBody = ex.GetResponseBody();

            //  Serialize the error information:
            ApiError apiError = errorBody.FromJson<ApiError>();

            //  Throw a new exception based on this information:
            throw new MailChimpAPIException(apiError.Error, ex, apiError);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorBody = ex.GetResponseBody();

            //  Serialize the error information:
            ApiError apiError = errorBody.FromJson<ApiError>();

            //  Throw a new exception based on this information:
            throw new MailChimpAPIException(apiError.Error, ex, apiError);
        }
```

Comment: Hi, do you have any solution? I have same problem with handling 500 error.

Comment: Sorry I don't remember if I got a solution and I don't have the code base.